# Find which repository I cloned

Tags: git

I've got a bare git repo on my test and production web servers.  I cloned one of the two to my dev machine.

How can I figure out which one I cloned? That is, if I do a `git push`, which repo will I be affecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git remote -v`

That will print the full list of remotes for the current repository, plus the URL they pull and push to/from.

By default git requires you to be explicit about what remote you are using, but you can configure it to default to `origin`, which is standardly the place it was cloned from.  (...but you don't have to call it that, and you can change that later.)

Answer (score 1):

Specifically:

```
git remote show origin
```

but Daniel's answer yields more info.

Comment: +1 because this shows more info about origin, the remote you actually care about.